# How to dynamically change image when view port is changed in react.js/Styled Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styled-components

```
import { GlobalStyle } from '../Theme';
import styled from 'styled-components';

import heroMobileImg from '../assets/images/about/mobile/image-about-hero.jpg';
import worldClassTalentMobileImg from '../assets/images/about/mobile/image-world-class-talent.jpg';
import realDealMobileImg from '../assets/images/about/mobile/image-real-deal.jpg';

import heroTabletImg from '../assets/images/about/tablet/image-about-hero.jpg';
import worldClassTalentTabletImg from '../assets/images/about/tablet/image-world-class-talent.jpg';
import realDealTabletImg from '../assets/images/about/tablet/image-real-deal.jpg';

import Header from '../components/Header';
import Footer from '../components/Footer';

const StyledAboutPageContainer = styled.div`
    .about-banner-container {
        height: 71.5rem;
    }
    .banner-img{
        background-image:url(${heroMobileImg});
    }

    @media screen and (min-width: 800px) {
        .banner-img{
        background-image:url(${heroTabletImg});
    }
    }
`;
function About() {
    return (
        <StyledAboutPageContainer>
            <GlobalStyle />
            <main>
                <Header />
                <div className="about-banner-container">
                    <div className="banner-img"/>
                </div>

                <Footer />
            </main>
        </StyledAboutPageContainer>
    );
}

export default About;
```

I have around 5 different images need to display in this page and each of them has mobile,tablet, and desktop size. This is what I am currently doing, I import all the image first and then use media query to change its background image.

Well, I feel like there got be a better way to do this kind of work. I can pass the different image name with the following code

```
    let size = "";
    if (window.innerWidth < 800)
             size="mobile";
    else if (window.innerWidth > 800 && window.innerWidth <= 1100)
             size="tablet";
    else 
         size="desktop";
    const curImg = require(`../assets/images/about/${size}/${name}.jpg`)
```

The problem is I do not know how to let react re-render image when the size is changed at the different break points.

Comment: You can use this library https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-media#readme to watch window changes, or even create your own media query listener, I haven't tested the performance or which one is better but I think that should accomplish what you want to do in the second code snippet.

Answer (score 1):

If you dont need to support IE, check this [Responsive_images](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Multimedia_and_embedding/Responsive_images)

In sort you can do it with plain HTML

```
<picture>
  <source media="(max-width: 799px)" srcset="elva-480w-close-portrait.jpg">
  <source media="(min-width: 800px)" srcset="elva-800w.jpg">
  <img src="elva-800w.jpg" alt="Chris standing up holding his daughter Elva">
</picture>
```